# Is there a SE site where I can ask about a question related to the change of address service on USPS website?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

Is there a place on Stack Exchange where I can ask the following question related to the change of address service on the USPS website? I have sent USPS an email, but wouldn't expect them to help me solve the problem.

On https://moversguide.usps.com/mgo/disclaimer, after I filled out the information, when I clicked "Next", it doesn't move to the next webpage. Nor does it say anything wrong. I don't know whether that is a technical problem, or because I am outside the US (can anyone in or outside US verify that with me?).

I searched "USPS" on https://stackexchange.com/search?q=USPS, and the results don't imply much to me.
People working with USPS API may know about it. People frequenting the webapps site may as well, I guess.

---

UPDATE:

I just learned about using the console of my web browser to get some information when interacting on the webpage. After I typed in all the information, and clicked "Next", the console showed the following message

```
app.a7b49c3e.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: grecaptcha is not defined
    at app.a7b49c3e.js:1:90970
    at f (chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:73:16624)
    at Generator._invoke (chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:73:17950)
    at Generator.next (chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:73:17049)
    at r (chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1:22794)
    at s (chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1:22997)
    at chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1:23056
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1:22937
    at a.recaptchaTokenGet (app.a7b49c3e.js:1:91128)
(anonymous) @ app.a7b49c3e.js:1
f @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:73
(anonymous) @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:73
(anonymous) @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:73
r @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1
s @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1
(anonymous) @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1
(anonymous) @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1
recaptchaTokenGet @ app.a7b49c3e.js:1
(anonymous) @ app.a7b49c3e.js:1
f @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:73
(anonymous) @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:73
(anonymous) @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:73
r @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1
s @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1
(anonymous) @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1
(anonymous) @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1
recaptchaV3Validate @ app.a7b49c3e.js:1
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.59c5a8c1.js:1
f @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:73
(anonymous) @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:73
(anonymous) @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:73
r @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1
s @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1
Promise.then (async)
r @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1
s @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1
Promise.then (async)
r @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1
s @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1
(anonymous) @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1
(anonymous) @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1
validate @ bootstrap.59c5a8c1.js:1
submit @ bootstrap.59c5a8c1.js:1
re @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:32
n @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:32
i._wrapper @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:32
```

Also see the following screenshot:

[image]

I was wondering if it is a technical problem under GFW, and where I could ask about the problem?

Comment: Did you try contacting USPS via the [_Contact Us_ page](https://www.usps.com/help/contact-us.htm)? That might be the best course of action

Comment: @SamOnela I did. I don't have any confidence that they could help me. Normally I wouldn't think of Stack Exchange when it comes to USPS related questions, but SE is the only internet forum that I know accessible under GFW.

Comment: @IanCampbell I tried chrome and firefox on laptop and phone, before asking

Comment: GFW = [Great Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall)

Comment: The last edit to the question, consider [su]. You might be interested in [Looking for a canonical about troubleshooting issues about using web applications?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14891/152004)

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Thanks for keeping helping me clarify that. I can't  access Wikipedia, and searching for sensitive words such as VPN or GFW can result in Internet disconnection and slowing down.

Comment: @Rubén Thanks for following up my update!

Answer (score 4):

You can ask your question about: "I don't know whether that is a technical problem, or because I am outside the US (**can anyone** in or outside US verify that with me?).", or how others went about changing their address **in person** (example: Embassy) on a few of our sites:

- [Expatriates.SE](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/search?q=USPS) - 23 results

  - Expatriates' [Help - on-topic](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- [Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=USPS) - 61 results

  - Travel's [Help - on-topic](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Travel.SE's help seems to imply that our expatriates site is the better choice for questions **about** changing your address while abroad, **but** technical support isn't our specialty; so be certain to read the help.

You **might** obtain assistance in our chat rooms, where you can ask: "Is it working for them?".

- Expatriates' Chat room: ["The Embassy"](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13567/the-embassy)
- Travel Chat room: ["You Are Here"](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here)

Answer (score 3):

First try using your web browser in private / incognito mode, using a different computer and even a different network connection. Also ask a friend in a different location to help you filling the form for you.

Try https://chat.stackexchange.com

---

Try [Expatriates SE](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/tour). They have related tags like `[usa]`, `[postal-system]`, `[online-resources]`.

Try also [Law SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour). They have related tags like  `[united-states]`,`[postal-service]`.

By "try" I mean checkout the mentioned tags, the site chat rooms, the corresponding per-site meta.

---

[Web Applications SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour) is a site for questions about using web applications including websites that behave as a web application, but [*troubleshooting*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troubleshooting) like questions are off-topic.

By the other hand, there are several sites that might have a different stand about troubleshooting.

[[discussion] troubleshooting is:question](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdiscussion%5D%20troubleshooting%20is%3Aquestion) returns all the questions having the `[discussion]` tag and the *troubleshooting* keyword. All per-site metas have the `[discussion]`tag so it's very likely that this search results will show all the site that have discussions about *troubleshooting*.

Recently I posted the following questions in Meta Super User

- [2023 stand about "troubleshooting"](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14888/152004)
- [Looking for a canonical about troubleshooting issues about using web applications?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14891/152004)

---

[[troubleshooting] is:question](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btroubleshooting%5D+is%3Aquestion) returns all the questions in the Stack Exchange network tagged `[troubleshooting]`. You might add the web browser and operating system that you are using among other keywords and search operators and play with different tags.

In Meta Super User there is a discussion about some tags including `[troubleshooting]`:

- [Burninate [diagnostic], [troubleshooting], and [debugging]?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/12900/152004)